# 301 and 302 Redirect mixing URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to do `301 Redirect` on my WP redirecting old pages to new pages and i have edited the `htaccess` file but some of my URLs are being mixed, for example:

`Redirect 302 https://www.my-site.it/programme/old-resources/ https://www.my-site.it/en/programme`/new-resources

I get in my URL bar:

```
https://www.my-site.it/en/programme/resources/old-resources/
```

which causes a `404 error`

I also tried using a 301 redirect WP plugin but faced the same problem.

What can I do?

Comment: Your example should not work at all in the first place. The first (or with status code given, second) argument for `Redirect` should be an URL _path_, not a full, absolute URL.

Comment: `Redirect 302 /old-path/old-page/ /new-path/new-page/` or `Redirect 302 /old-path/old-page/ https://www.my-site.com/new-path/new-page/` ?

Comment: Depends. If `/old-path/old-page/foobarbaz` got requested, and you wanted to redirect that to `/new-path/new-page/foobarbaz`, then yes.

Comment: but why these 2 redirects: `Redirect 301 /program/ /resource2/` 
`Redirect 302 /program/resource1/ /flicorno-d-oro/`
redirect here:
`www.mywebsite.com/resource2/resource1/` ??

Comment: For what exact input URL now? `/program/resource1/`? Because the directive does prefix-based matching, and appends any excess to the target URL.

Comment: I have solved the problem reordering all 120 Redirects (just like you said: it uses a prefix-based matching) ... now they are parsed properly and in correct order. Thanks